# How do i check for tiles around a specific tile?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game.

The game's world is represented by a tilemap. The tiles correspond to values in a 2D array.

I would like to use a special "corner" wall sprite if any three wall tiles make an L shape. That is,

```
V
##      #    >##
#      ##     #
        ^
```

The tiles indicated with arrows should be corner tiles.

I have the code to search for the wall but I don't know how to identify which tiles are the corner tiles.

My code is:

```
import pygame, sys
import Sprites
import random

from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()


fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

cloudx = -200
cloudy = 0

infoObject = pygame.display.Info()

DIRT = 0
GRASS = 1
WATER = 2
COAL = 3
CLOUD = 4
WALL = 5
CWALL = 6

controls = {
    DIRT : 49,
    GRASS: 50,
    WATER: 51,
    COAL : 52,
    WALL : 53
}

infoObject = pygame.display.Info()

w = infoObject.current_w
h = infoObject.current_h

TILESIZE  = 40
MAPWIDTH  = 15
MAPHEIGHT = 15

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)

resources = [DIRT, GRASS, WATER, COAL]

textures =  {
            DIRT  : pygame.image.load('Sprites/Dirt.png'),
            GRASS : pygame.image.load('Sprites/tile130.png'),
            WATER : pygame.image.load('Sprites/Water.png'),
            COAL  : pygame.image.load('Sprites/Coal.png'),
            CLOUD : pygame.image.load('Sprites/Cloud.png'),
            WALL  : pygame.image.load('Sprites/Swall.png'),
            CWALL : pygame.image.load('Sprites/Swall.png')
          }

playerPos = [0,0]

inventory = {
            DIRT   :  0,
            GRASS  :  0,
            WATER  :  0,
            COAL   :  0,
            WALL   :  10,
            }

tilemap = [[DIRT for w in range(MAPWIDTH)] for h in range(MAPHEIGHT)]



DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE,MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE + 50))

pygame.display.set_caption('M I N E C R A F T -- 2D')
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('Sprites/player.png'))

PLAYER = pygame.image.load('Sprites/Player.png').convert_alpha()

for rw in range(MAPHEIGHT):
    for cl in range(MAPWIDTH):
        randomNumber = random.randint(0,15)
        if randomNumber == 0:
            tile = COAL
        elif randomNumber == 1 or randomNumber == 2:
            tile = WATER
        elif randomNumber >= 3 and randomNumber <=7:
            tile = GRASS
        else:
            tile = DIRT

        tilemap[rw][cl] = tile

INVFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 18)

print(tilemap)

while True:

    currentTile = tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]]

    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BLACK)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
#        print(event)
        if event.type == QUIT:

            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:

            for key in controls:


                if (event.key == controls[key]):

                    if inventory[key] > 0:

                        inventory[key] -=1

                        inventory[currentTile] += 1

                        tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]] = key

            if(event.key == K_RIGHT) and playerPos[0] < MAPWIDTH - 1:
                playerPos[0]+=1

            elif(event.key == K_LEFT) and playerPos[0] > 0:
                playerPos[0]-=1

            elif(event.key == K_DOWN) and playerPos[1] < MAPHEIGHT - 1:
                playerPos[1]+=1

            elif(event.key == K_UP) and playerPos[1] > 0:
                playerPos[1]-=1

            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                currentTile = tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]]
                inventory[currentTile] += 1
                tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]] = DIRT

    for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
        for column in range(MAPWIDTH):
                DISPLAYSURF.blit(textures[tilemap[row][column]],(column*TILESIZE, row*TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
                DISPLAYSURF.blit(PLAYER,(playerPos[0]*TILESIZE,playerPos[1]*TILESIZE))


    DISPLAYSURF.blit(textures[CLOUD].convert_alpha(),(cloudx,cloudy))
    cloudx +=1

    if cloudx > MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE:
        cloudy = random.randint(0, MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE)
        cloudx = -200


    placePosition = 10
    for item in resources:
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(textures[item],(placePosition, MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE+10))
        placePosition+=50
        textObj = INVFONT.render(str(inventory[item]), True, WHITE, BLACK)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(textObj,(placePosition, MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE+20))
        placePosition += 50

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(24)

    for x in range(MAPWIDTH):
        for y in range(MAPHEIGHT):
            if tilemap[x][y] == WALL:
                go_left = x > 1
                go_right = x < MAPWIDTH - 1
                go_up = y > 1
                go_down = y < MAPHEIGHT - 1
                if go_left:
                    tilemap[x - 1][y] = CWALL
                    if go_up:
                        pass
                if go_right:
                    tilemap[x + 1][y] = WALL 
                if go_up:
                    pass
                if go_down:
                    pass
                print('WALL')


    pygame.display.update()
```

And here are the links to the sprites:
https://framadrop.org/r/fmReup_rTK#bMSywSUa7nxb1qL/a4FIbns+VaspgE0c/FU+9f1drHI=

https://framadrop.org/r/pBOfrnKcdT#eNEZQ9QjX5Cl6X4gH4UwdIg3eBPnY/L4WcSGYtUR5PE=

https://framadrop.org/r/ZFfTz_Lq9V#2Nd5ba1iE7miyFg8JpPFvwabAkdnHds/GfVkSAQeJaQ=

https://framadrop.org/r/gN9Y748L9G#Z552pPpgjTcSubt9tn74mZ0tT1COv7UCFdkUq2DorAU=

https://framadrop.org/r/d9k4hyCUni#OTza8UbsR8Am/R1PA9MAWkLDPRDBsT1rAHMgr61jusc=

https://framadrop.org/r/1mv777OR6d#pkqwaQrmVRElUPcdEV5K4UhmALsJSYX7z3WtrZXl4TE=

https://framadrop.org/r/CyF-tk7yUb#IFexcePe418JizElZzCJzDENTJPDfz7i1nr+lGns0rU=

https://framadrop.org/r/VzVfAz6bnL#oLHivyHPtTD8+IxliDD4yc+6LS9kpGyEp1HNFGUsBHo=

https://framadrop.org/r/0V0ShMH0uq#PZHdPSQNbgL7QqH2niwdS4HO34ZRMfIlhpvpRqbWwng=

Comment: Aren't the neighbouring tiles just x+/-1 and y+/-1? Also what is this Sprites you import? I don't know where to find it so I cannot run the code...

Comment: Yes but i have to tell it what x and y values the wall are at otherwise it doesnt know what to choose. And how can i give you the sprites? What works best for you?

Comment: I don't understand... whenever you enter ``if tilemap[x][y] == WALL:`` then `x` and `y` correspond to a wall, don't they?

Comment: Yes but i need to then give those x y coordinates a name. For example: pos = x,y. But it doesnt work like that and thats where im having issues

Comment: I finally understand what you are trying to do, good edit! Now one last question: are all your walls L-shaped or can you also have T- and X-shapes (or even more complexe shapes)?

Comment: In the end im gonna have L, T, and + shapes. But as of right now the only walls that i have implemented are walls that are verticle, horizontal, and corners.

Comment: OK, so for now my answer should let you do everything ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, I'm not sure what the problem is... let me just show you what I would do so we can discuss further if needed:

```
for x in range(MAPWIDTH):
    for y in range(MAPHEIGHT):
        if tilemap[x][y] == WALL:
            # there is a wall at indices x and y
            # get neighbouring tiles (check for limits)
            go_left  = x > 1
            go_right = x < MAPWIDTH - 1
            go_up    = y > 1
            go_down  = y < MAPHEIGHT - 1

            if go_left:
                # you can use x-1
                tilemap[x-1][y] = WALL  # set left tile to WALL
                if go_up:
                    # do something in the diagonal with x-1 y-1?
                    pass
            if go_right:
                # you can use x+1
                tilemap[x+1][y] = WALL  # set right tile to WALL
            if go_up:
                pass # same story
            if go_down:
                pass # and again
```

**EDIT** here is a simple (hence hopefully easy to understand) way of doing this

In order to make the textures clean, I first had to rotate the wall and corner to get all possible configurations (vertical/horizontal for the wall, and all four possibilities for the corner)

```
VWALL = 5
HWALL = 6
CORNERLD = 7
CORNERRD = 8
CORNERLU = 9
CORNERRU = 10

controls = {
    DIRT  : 49,
    GRASS : 50,
    WATER : 51,
    COAL  : 52,
    VWALL : 53,
    HWALL : 54,
    CORNERLD: 55,
    CORNERRD: 56,
    CORNERLU: 57,
    CORNERRU: 58,
}

tex_wall   = pygame.image.load('Sprites/Swall.png')
tex_corner = pygame.image.load('Sprites/Corner.png')

textures =  {
            DIRT    : pygame.image.load('Sprites/Dirt.png'),
            GRASS   : pygame.image.load('Sprites/tile130.png'),
            WATER   : pygame.image.load('Sprites/Water.png'),
            COAL    : pygame.image.load('Sprites/Coal.png'),
            CLOUD   : pygame.image.load('Sprites/Cloud.png'),
            HWALL   : pygame.transform.rotate(tex_wall, 90),
            VWALL   : tex_wall,
            CORNERRD: tex_corner,
            CORNERLD: pygame.transform.flip(tex_corner, True, False),
            CORNERLU: pygame.transform.flip(tex_corner, True, True),
            CORNERRU: pygame.transform.flip(tex_corner, False, True),
          }
```

I created a wall dict to quickly check all 6 possibilities for walls with `in walls`

```
walls = {
    VWALL : None,
    HWALL : None,
    CORNERLD: None,
    CORNERRD: None,
    CORNERLU: None,
    CORNERRU: None,
}
```

And then I check the map

```
for x in range(MAPWIDTH):
    for y in range(MAPHEIGHT):
        if tilemap[x][y] in walls:
            # there is a wall at indices x and y
            # get neighbouring tiles (check for limits)
            go_left  = x > 1
            go_right = x < MAPWIDTH - 1
            go_up    = y > 1
            go_down  = y < MAPHEIGHT - 1

            l_wall = False
            r_wall = False
            u_wall = False
            d_wall = False

            if go_left and tilemap[x-1][y] in walls:
                # left tile is WALL
                l_wall = True
            if go_right and tilemap[x+1][y] in walls:
                # right tile is WALL
                r_wall = True
            if go_up and tilemap[x][y-1] in walls:
                u_wall = True
            if go_down and tilemap[x][y+1] in walls:
                d_wall = True

            if l_wall and u_wall:
                # upper left corner
                tilemap[x][y] = CORNERLU
            elif l_wall and d_wall:
                # down left corner
                tilemap[x][y] = CORNERRU
            elif r_wall and u_wall:
                # upper left corner
                tilemap[x][y] = CORNERLD
            elif r_wall and d_wall:
                # down left corner
                tilemap[x][y] = CORNERRD
            elif (l_wall or r_wall) and not (u_wall or d_wall):
                # tiles in a vertical wall, use VWALL
                tilemap[x][y] = VWALL
            elif (u_wall or d_wall) and not (l_wall or r_wall):
                # tiles in a horizontal wall, use HWALL
                tilemap[x][y] = HWALL
```

And we get

[image: Your new Minecraft 2D]

Note that there are random configurations of wall that will not look good, though (T-shapes...) but these would require additional sprites.

The full code I used can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/GKYdRGKw)

**EDIT2** note that you will have to update a few more things to make everything work smoothly (e.g. wall uptake in the inventory)
Also running this check every loop is costly, so you should declare an `env_changed` boolean to make the test only when a change was made to the environment.

For the inventory, you will need

```
if currentTile in walls:
    inventory[VWALL] += 1
```

this makes VWALL the default wall in the inventory and the loop takes care of switching it to a proper one for the display.
For the rest, well... it's your game, so I'll let you figure it out ;)

Comment: Would you like the sprites so you can test yourself? I think that would really help both of us

Comment: yes, or any open source stuff like [framadrop](https://framadrop.org/) (please update your post with the link to the file, so anyone can see it and test)

Comment: well it wouldnt alow me to post the links onto my post so i had to post them onto your comment

Comment: Im gonna quickly run your code and see what happens, thanks

Comment: So what happens is it just places corner walls all the way down. I also updated the code so that corner walls are implemented

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow, in the meantime, maybe you should make a picture of what you want: my code was just aimed at showing you how to get the tiles around a wall, the rest is up to you (change the `pass` into useful code)

Comment: This is what it would look like with working code, https://framadrop.org/r/07h5X2UcrB#ay0Bbf7LvAozRym7slvO9Zld2C4WOMa/+uBXWyiNyhY=

Comment: Also i added in the side wall but for your testing that could just be a regular wall

Comment: here you go, I updated the answer to give you a working example (full code in the bottom link)

Comment: Wow man this is incredible, ive been trying to tackle this issue for the past week. Thankyou very much!

Comment: I ran the code exactly as you have it but its not doing what i intended it too. The idea is that if i place, for example, two walls, one on top of the other, and then one to the left of the upper wall, then the upper wall will become a corner because it would be the corner of the building. Ill upload an immage of what i mean

Comment: It's just that in my code the check is run in static, before the loop, you just have to move it to the loop to get that

Comment: Ohhh makes sense, I was wondering why you put it before the loop XD

Comment: I added a few last tips to help you get started with the new env and speed things up, you'll have to figure the rest on your own, though. And please don't forget to accept the answer afterwards to show that your issue is solved ;) Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by generating a set offsets

```
// 1
//0 2  Neighbour directions
// 3
//       0  1  2  3  Corresponding offsets
dx   = [-1, 0, 1, 0]
dy   = [0, -1, 0, 1]
Nmax = 4
```

Now, I can get the n-values of the neighbouring walls, like so:

```
nwalls = []
for n in range(Nmax):    #n is the direction of the neighbour
  #Ensure that the neighbour tile, identified as (x+dx[n], y+dy[n])
  #is in the map and check to see if it is a wall
  if 1<x+dx[n]<WIDTH and 1<y+dy[n]<HEIGHT and tilemap[x+dx[n]][y+dy[n]]==WALL:  
    nwalls.append(n) #Neighbour was a wall, add its direction to this list
```

Now, I can convert my list into a tile name:

```
#nwalls is a list of all the directions pointing to a wall
nwalls.sort()            #Sort list, e.g. 3,1,2 -> 1,2,3
nwalls = map(str,nwalls) #Convert from numbers to strings
nwalls = ''.join(nwalls) #Append strings together: ['1','2','3'] -> '123'
if nwalls:               #If the string is not empty
  nwalls = 'corner_tile_{0}.jpg'.format(nwalls) #Convert string to tile name
```

Now I just need a bunch of tiles named, e.g.:

```
corner_tile_01.jpg
corner_tile_013.jpg
```

Then I can say:

```
if nwalls: #Only true if this was a corner
  Code to display the tile whose name is stored in `nwalls`
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response, but i find this all very confusing. Im young and i had my very first look at python last week but trust me i am learning very quickly. Could you please simplify this?

Comment: @scooter505: Don't use your age as an excuse; I'll help you in the same way regardless of your age. Which part of this do you find confusing?

Comment: @scooter505: I've added a number of comments to the code.

Comment: Your right, i shouldnt use it as an excuse because regardless of my age id still find this confusing, my apologies. But i find all of it confusing. There are some "commands" in there that i have never seen and im not sure what they do. Is there anywhere you could dm me so this conversation doesnt have to take place in comments? If you know of any websites, id be willing to do that

Comment: Thanks for the edits, they make it make more sense but could you please explain the beginning part. Im not sure what that stuff means.

Comment: The idea is that I would like to be able to look at all of the neighbours of a central cell. These neighbours are at `x-1,y` and `x,y-1` and `x+1,y` and `x,y+1`. It's annoying to have to write those out each time. So, instead, I put the `+1` and `-1` into arrays named `dx` and `dy`. The array has 4 entries. So each neighbour is at `x+dx[n],y+dy[n]` for some value of `n`. This way I can write a for-loop that looks at all the neighbours.

Comment: This lets me easily ask questions like, "Does any neighbouring cell have a bad guy?" (`baddie=False // for n in range(Nmax): // if 1<x+dx[n]<WIDTH and 1<y+dy[n]<HEIGHT and baddies[x+dx[n]][y+dy[n]]>0: // baddie=True`) or, in this case, make a list of what's in the neighbouring spaces.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, now my final question, hopefully, is how would i implement this into my code? Could you make an edit on my original post showing me?